# Center items vertically in owl carousel, Canvas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to (1) get an image carousel to vertically center images, and (2) get the carousel to shrink to the height of the smallest image [i.e. not have wasted white space]. This is sort of a "multiple image" carousel, like this one: https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/clients-brand-logo-carousel-slider-20683486.

I don't know what classes to add where. Obviously looked at `d-flex` + `justify-items` + `align-items`, and some other SO posts suggesting that I change the `oc-item` and related classes to `height: 100%; position: relative;` but none of those seemed to have the desired effect.

Given the naming, I assume this is an implementation of the owl carousel (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

HTML, which includes many elements that are added-in via JS (not my JS, I'm using a package I purchased from Themeforest, called Canvas https://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/blocks.html... I think it's the one on the bottom of this page https://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/slider-owl.html **the CSS and JS should be the same for this page as what I'm using**):

```
<section id="content">
  <div class="content-wrap p-0" id="content-wrap-logos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fancy-title title-center title-border m-4">
          <h4><small>AS SEEN WITH</small></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="oc-images" class="owl-carousel image-carousel carousel-widget align-middle align-items-center owl-loaded owl-drag with-carousel-dots" data-items-xs="2" data-items-sm="3" data-items-lg="4" data-items-xl="5">
           <div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 2369px;">
               <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 243.2px; margin-right: 20px;">
                 <div class="oc-item">
                     <a href="..." target="_blank"><img src="..." alt="..."></a>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 243.2px; margin-right: 20px;">
                 <div class="oc-item">
                     <a href="..." target="_blank"><img src="i..." alt="..."></a>
                 </div>
              </div>
              ... etc ...
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="owl-nav">
         <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev disabled">
            <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
         </button>
         <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next">
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="owl-dots">
         <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
         <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button></div></div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are not shared the css code but here is the solution.

Give anchor display block , min-height and vertical-align middle. So image come vertically center.

```
.owl-item a {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 38px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Viking; unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I updated the question to make the CSS and JS more clear.